# How to create shared styles using styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to achieve something like the following output using styled components (shared selectors).

```css
.styleOne, .styleTwo {
    color: blue; /* shared */
}

.styleOne {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.styleTwo {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

I've tried:

1 - (this one makes sense why it doesn't render my desired output)

```js
const shared = `color: blue;`

const StyleOne = styled.div`
    font-size: 10px;
    ${shared}
`

const StyleTwo = styled.div`
    font-size: 20px;
    ${shared}
`
```

2 -

```js
const Shared = styled.div`
    color: blue;
`

const StyleOne = styled(Shared)`
    font-size: 10px;
`

const StyleTwo = styled(Shared)`
    font-size: 20px;
`
```

3 -

```js
const shared = css`
    color: blue;
`

const StyleOne = styled.div`
    font-size: 10px;
    ${shared}
`

const StyleTwo = styled.div`
    font-size: 20px;
    ${shared}
`
```

All the above result in something like the following:

```css
.styleOne {
    color: blue; /* duplicated */
    font-size: 10px;
}

.styleTwo {
    color: blue; /* duplicated */
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Technically the styles are shared in each approach from a code perspective. However, the rules are still duplicated. I was hoping to be able to share the CSS rules themselves.

An analogy in SASS would be - I want to use a placeholder instead of a mixin.

To add some context on why I want to achieve this, I want to have a smaller HTML document for performance reasons. I'm imagining in a large app where I'm sharing a lot of styles, the style block may get huge.

Comment: Styled-components by design creates new classes each time you “extend” the component. It doesn’t compare and merge, but overwrites CSS properties by using class specificity. That said, you can create global styles using static class names by passing the static class name to the component as a string. Ex: `<Header className=“example” />`. This global class name will then be appended after the dynamic class name that styled components generates.

Comment: @MattCarlotta - Thanks for the reply. I guess based on what you said what I'm trying to do isn't really in the spirit of styled components. Do you think there is any performance concerns in large apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ***large apps*** is too ambiguous to state whether or not you'll have performance issues -- whether it's from downloading/executing JS or downloading parsing CSS and/or fetching other media (fonts, images, etc). That said, styled-components applies styles in the `head` during run-time and does an excellent job of deferring them until they're required in the DOM.

Take a look at this [example](https://b94l4.csb.app/) and follow these steps:

1. Inspect the DOM and within the `Elements` tab expand the `head`
2. Look for this `style` tag and expand it: `<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.2.0"></style>`
3. With the inspector still open, navigate to other pages and notice how class names are generated on-the-fly
4. Once the classes have been assigned, they're then reused

This has the similar effect of using [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#css-modules) (scoped classes) without the extra request to download the required CSS, and it automatically prefixes CSS properties without any additional plugins.

**So the question becomes**: Is it better to have more Javascript (packaging and running styled-components in run-time) and less CSS (less requests to download CSS per page) or more CSS and ***potentially*** less Javascript? You'll need to run metrics -- like a [lighthouse test](https://web.dev/measure/) -- in production to determine which is more performant; otherwise, it's just going to be a guess/personal opinion.

Either way, you're going to be running into some sort of render blocking, whether it's downloading/parsing CSS or downloading/executing JS.